# How to add QPixmap to QWebEngineView

Tags: qt

I'm dynamically creating html page as QString and set it to QWebEngineView, 
for static resource images I have no issue, I can do :

```
    html += "<img src='qrc:/img/logo.png'/>"
```

But for dynamic prepared QPixmap how to insert it?.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/18231/qtwebkit-can-not-display-image-in-case-of-local-network-path/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to convert it to base64:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QBuffer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView view;

    QPixmap pixmap(512, 512);
    pixmap.fill(QColor("salmon"));

    // to bytes
    QByteArray bytes;
    QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    pixmap.save(&buffer, "PNG");
    // to base64
    QByteArray ba = bytes.toBase64();

    QString html;
    html += QString("<img src='data:image/png;base64,%1'/>").arg(QString(ba));
    view.setHtml(html);
    view.resize(1024, 750);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```